# How to make a .shar file?

Tags: scripts, archive

I want to know how to make these shar files, i mean to import files to this file and extract them. Could somebody explain me?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: oh no problem. At least you typed it in english ;-) I've seen japanese, russian and more :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`shar` is not installed by default and it is part of `shar-utils`. To install:

```
sudo apt-get install sharutils
```

The man page for [shar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/shar) has a good amount of information, warnings and examples. From the link:

> **Description**
>
> Shar creates "shell archives" (or shar files) which are in text format and can be mailed. These files may be unpacked later by executing them with /bin/sh. The resulting archive is sent to standard out unless the -o option is given. A wide range of features provide extensive flexibility in manufacturing shars and in specifying shar "smartness". Archives may be "vanilla" or comprehensive.

and it has some examples:

Examples

```
shar *.c > cprog.shar          # all C prog sources
shar -Q *.[ch] > cprog.shar    # non-verbose, .c and .h files
shar -B -l28 -oarc.sh *.arc    # all binary .arc files, into
                               # files arc.sh.01 thru arc.sh.NN
shar -f /lcl/src/u*.c > u.sh   # use only the filenames
```

Have a look though all the options at the man page for compression, integrity checks, internationalization and more.

---

It has a counterpart called [unshar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unshar)

> **Description**
>
> Unshar scans mail messages looking for the start of a shell archive. It then passes the archive through a copy of the shell to unpack it. It will accept multiple files. If no files are given, standard input is used.

To extract the files in a shar archive:

```
$ sh example.shar
```

`unshar` is another way to extract files. This also handles `.shar` files that begin with email headers or other extraneous data.

```
$ unshar example.shar
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to install sharutils

```
sudo apt-get install sharutils
```

Once installed, you can refer to its man file to know how to use it.

```
man shar
```

Basic syntax is:

```
shar <list of files>
```

Comment: And where do the created shar files go?

Comment: @ciro into a container like a tar or zip file would. You then put the .shar file into a mail and send it to someone. And that person can unshar it